# Getting the property of an object

Tags: php, joomla

So if I use the following code in Joomla

```
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$modules = JModuleHelper::getModules( 'nav' );
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $modules );
echo '</pre>';
```

The following is returned:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Main Menu
            [module] => mod_menu
            [position] => nav
            [content] => 
            [showtitle] => 0
            [params] => {"menutype":"mainmenu","base":"","startLevel":"1","endLevel":"0","showAllChildren":"1","tag_id":"","class_sfx":"","window_open":"","layout":"joomberui:TopNav","moduleclass_sfx":" contain-to-grid","cache":"1","cache_time":"900","cachemode":"itemid","module_tag":"div","bootstrap_size":"0","header_tag":"h3","header_class":"","style":"0"}
            [menuid] => 0
            [name] => menu
            [style] => 
        )

)
```

If I add `echo $modules[0]->params->menu;`
then I get just the params

What would I use to get only `moduleclass_sfx` ?

Thanks!
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The params field looks like json data, a json object to be precise as it is wrapped in `{` and `}` so to make it usable in PHP, try this

```
$params = json_decode($modules[0]->params);

echo 'moduleclass_sfx = ' . $params->moulesclass_sfx;
```